# How do I inform the rest of the system my shell has changed from zsh to bash?

Tags: bash, zsh, login, passwd

I installed `zsh` because I thought I might prefer it over `bash`. I don't, and to revert it I have used `chsh -s /bin/bash`, which as  myself gives `You may not change the shell for 'cat'.`

I also changed my line in `/etc/passwd` from:

```
cat:x:1000:1000:cat,,,:/home/cat:/bin/zsh
```

to

```
cat:x:1000:1000:cat,,,:/home/cat:/usr/bin/bash
```

(because `which bash` gave `/usr/bin/bash`).

GNOME Terminal, `xterm`, Terminology, etc all now agree my shell is `bash`.

But, when I enter a virtual terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd>, where `n` is a numeric key, and try to log in as myself, something like

```
Ubuntu 15.10 mint-kitty ttyN

mint-kitty login: cat
Password:


/bin/zsh: no such file or directory 
exit
```

appears and then I am logged out.

I can log in to a graphical session just fine. (MDM + Cinnamon.)

As far as I am aware, a user's login shell is determined by `/etc/passwd`. There are no references to `zsh` in `.bashrc` or `.profile`, nor in `/etc/profile`.

How do I make the rest of the system aware my shell is not `zsh`?

Comment: If you ran `sudo chsh`, you changed root's shell. Not your own. Changing your own shell should be done with just `chsh`.

Comment: @muru I got `You may not change the shell for 'cat'.`

Comment: Very strange. Even stranger is that your `passwd` line shows `/usr/bin/bash` as the shell, where one would expect `/bin/zsh`, given the error you got in TTY. What did you mean by "I changed my line in /etc/passwd"?

Comment: Do you have an exec /bin/zsh in your bash startup files?

Comment: @muru I updated my question, hopefully it's more clear

Comment: @JeffSchaller no, I checked `.bashrc` and `.profile`.

Comment: perhaps getty (or whatever's listening on the virt term) has cached /etc/passwd? could try HUPping them

Comment: @JeffSchaller I've rebooted a few times since making the changes

Comment: Does this happen if you SSH to localhost? What does `echo $SHELL` in a terminal say?

Comment: @muru `echo $SHELL` is `/usr/bin/bash`, and I can't quite figure out how to `ssh` to `localhost`, as it says the password for `cat@mint-kitty` is incorrect

Comment: Are you in some kind of distributed authentication environment (LDAP or NIS)? What does `getent passwd cat` say (and is it different from what you see in `/etc/passwd`)?

Comment: @steeldriver no, this is a personal system installed on my laptop privately, and the output of that command exactly matches my line in `passwd`.

Comment: Two entries for cat in /etc/passwd?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Nope, unless there's more than one `passwd`

Comment: You should change the entry in `/etc/passwd` to `/bin/bash`. The `chsh` command only works if called by root or if the current and the new shell are both listed in `/etc/shells`. That doesn't explain why `sshd` and `login`, but not `getent`, think your login shell is still zsh, rather than `/bin/bash`. Please post the output of `grep passwd /etc/nsswitch.conf` and the content of `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` and `/etc/pam.d/login` and the output of (as root) `grep -r /bin/zsh /etc`

Comment: I find quite odd that: [[ because `which bash` gave `/usr/bin/bash` ]]. Maybe bash was un-installed in the process to install zsh? What `type -a bash` from a prompt of zsh prints? Maybe re-install bash anyway (assuming debian like OS):  `apt-get install --reinstall bash` ? That will damage nothing and will ensure bash is installed.

Comment: @Gilles changing the entry in `passwd` from `/usr/bin/bash` to `/bin/bash` solved it. Please post that as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `chsh` command only lets you change your login shell from a shell that's listed in [`/etc/shells`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/shells.5.html), to a shell that's listed in `/etc/shells`. This is a security and safety feature: if an account has a restricted shell (not listed in `/etc/shells`), they can't upgrade their access by switching to another shell; and a user can't lock themselves out by switching to a shell that they can't change from. The root user is of course exempt from this restriction.

The check for `/etc/shells` does not consider alternate ways of naming a file such as symbolic links. If `/etc/shells` lists `/bin/bash`, then the entry in the user database must be `/bin/bash`, not `/bin/./bash` (which is the same file) or `/usr/bin/bash` (even if that's a symbolic link to `/bin/bash`).

If you're moving away from a shell, you need to run `chsh` to switch back before uninstalling the old shell, because the uninstallation will remove the shell from `/etc/shells`.

I recommend changing your shell back to `/bin/bash`; you'll need to do it as root. This way you'll be able to run `chsh` again in the future.

Under Linux, for a local account, the entry in `/etc/passwd` is what determines the user's login shell. (This is not true for some other Unix variants, where `/etc/passwd` is present for compatibility but is not the actual reference, so either `/etc/passwd` must not be modified or some synchronization command must be invoked after modifying it.)

I can't explain where the reference to `/bin/zsh` is lingering. Make sure there isn't a stray extra entry in `/etc/passwd`.