# Can't set my shell as fish shell due to error when using chsh due to lock file

Tags: command-line, fish

My problem: I cannot set my default shell for user 'student' on CentOS 7 to fish-shell. I installed fish-shell by downloading the .gz, configuring, make, make install.

```
output of which fish
/usr/local/bin/fish
```

running su from the standard 'student' account, I am able to escalate myself to root, which fish is set as the default shell. But when I run

```
student@localhost ~> whoami
root
student@localhost ~>
/root
student@localhost ~> sudo chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish student
Changing shell for student. 
chsh: user attribute not changed: Invalid contents of lock `/etc/passwd.lock`
```

looking at /etc/passwd I can see no changes occured.

Any idea what I can do? It looks like the lock files are preventing me from proceeding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I inform the rest of the system my shell has changed from zsh to bash?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260603/how-do-i-inform-the-rest-of-the-system-my-shell-has-changed-from-zsh-to-bash)

Comment: (1) Why does `whoami` report `root` when you are logged in as `student`?  (2) Why does your shell report `/root` when you type Enter?  (3) Does `/etc/passwd.lock` exist after you run `chsh`?  (4) What’s in it?  (5) What happens when you run `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish` (without `su` or `sudo`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like one of your previous attempts to change the `/etc/passwd` file has left some rubbish in the lock file.

That lock file prevents multiple updates that would cancel each other out. If you are the only one using that system, remove the file `/etc/passwd.lock` and try again.

Comment: its weird, this sorta fixed the issue. I deleted passwd.lock and shadow.lock and then ran sudo chsh -s /user/local/bin/fish student and i get "chsh: Shell not changed" .. thats it.

Comment: /etc/passwd is showing the shell listed as fish, restarting the machine to check if changes took

Comment: problem solved, than you Anthon

Comment: @Oscalation You do not need to reboot everytime you change passwd. At most, if changing a logged user, you need to login and logout.